# Can powering a USB-C port damage it?

Tags: power, usb-c

My question is a bit like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1284542/how-do-i-determine-if-my-laptop-can-charge-through-usb-c/1365742#1365742), but more general.

I have a laptop with a USB-C port (Asus [UX310UQ](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-Zenbook-UX310UQ/specifications/)-FB442T in this case, but I'd prefer a general answer), and a USB-C PD charger with the necessary power (65W charger, the same power the laptop came with).

Can either of them (charger or device) be damaged if I connect the two to test if it can charge or not?

Sometimes specifications are faulty (apart from the USB-C, the laptop has 2 USB3 and 1 USB2 ports, and not vice versa) or not cover certain capabilities (like in the mentioned topic), so it's better to test it. But I don't know if a USB-C device is not PD-compatible, and the charger powers it externally, things might go bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer, assuming everything is spec-compliant, is that no scenario should damage the laptop.

---

For a general answer, we can only talk specifications and assume all devices follow the spec. It's not possible to account for faulty implementations in a general sense.

USB-PD is a [negotiated protocol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361391/how-to-get-20-v-from-a-usb-c-charger), over the CC pins. Without the correct negotiation, a PD-*capable* charger will not output PD voltages. So, in that sense, you are safe.

There is a similar situation with plain Type-C (non-PD 5V) power: the CC pins are used to indicate whether one end is a power sink. Power sources are not supposed to apply current unless a sink is detected on the other end. A source-to-source connection, according to spec, will do nothing (power-wise). See *Universal Serial Bus Type-C Cable and Connector Specification R2.0*, in *§ 4.8 Power Sourcing and Charging*, *§ 4.5.3.1.5 Source to Source Behavior*, and various other locations.

There is the possibility of a dumb charger providing current without detection. This is still a safe situation if your laptop port follows specs.

> All USB Type-C ports shall tolerate being connected to USB power source supplying default USB power, e.g. a host being connected to a legacy USB charger that always supplies V<sub>BUS</sub>.

<sup>*Universal Serial Bus Type-C Cable and Connector Specification R2.0 § 4.6 Power*</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to know. FYI: this particular laptop did not charge (but didn't die either, which was the point of the question).

Comment: @Nyos FWIW there *is* a way you can charge these laptops off a USB-PD charger, but it's hacky, unsupported, and maybe a tad risky. You basically need an adapter or cable with a trigger chip that causes the PD source to output the laptop's normal charging voltage (~19 V is common, which works with PD in 20 V mode), and then plug it in to the normal barrel connector. I've done that to get one such laptop (also Asus) charging off a USB-PD battery bank. Again, this is a tad risky - you have to be careful that the PD source supports the correct current at that voltage, etc..

Comment: Yes, as I was doing my research, I've found this topic: https://superuser.com/questions/1506248/usb-c-to-laptop-charger?rq=1 there are some tips how to do this. Also, my laptop draws around 3.1A when charging and 0.8A when idle, so I could get away with a smaller one as well most of the time. I've bought a nice USB-C charger that is good for my phone, and making this work for my laptop as well could've saved me one thing less to carry.